# How to detect if a pdf is a one-column and two-column in python

Tags: python, pdf

So I work in NLP with hundreds of PDFs and the thing I hate is that since there is no one way of writing PDF I have to write a script to handle that (almost all the script is for the two-column PDF with tables and other weird stuff) and when I input one column one it gets messed up. Is there any way to detect if a PDF is one or two-column and run the fixing script only for the two column one after that? Please help me out with this.

This is what the PDFs look like
[One column PDF](https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/BarCvDescLJ11.pdf)
[Two column PDF](https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/Bill-Brown-Reprint.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

**disclaimer**: I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

`borb` has several classes that process PDF documents. These all implement `EventListener`. The idea is that they *listen* to the processing of pdf syntax, and process events (e.g.: an image has been rendered, a string was rendered, a new page has started, etc).

One of these implementations is `SimpleParagraphExtraction`. It attempts to use geometric information to determine which text should be separated from other text, and when something makes up a line of text, and when several lines make up a paragraph.

This is how you'd use it:

```py
        # read document
        l: SimpleParagraphExtraction = SimpleParagraphExtraction(maximum_multiplied_leading=Decimal(1.7))
        doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
        with open("input.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
            doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])
```

Once you've processed the PDF, you can now do something with the paragraphs you've detected.

```py
        for p in l.get_paragraphs_for_page(0):
            doc.get_page(0).add_annotation(
                SquareAnnotation(p.get_bounding_box(), stroke_color=HexColor("f1cd2e"))
            )
```

The above code adds a colored rectangle around each paragraph.

You can easily modify this code to determine how many paragraphs appear side-by-side. Which should help you determine whether something is single- or multi-column layout.

**edit:** This is a quick write-up I did:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import typing
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.text.simple_paragraph_extraction import SimpleParagraphExtraction
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.annotation.square_annotation import SquareAnnotation
from borb.pdf import HexColor
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from decimal import Decimal
import requests

open("example_001.pdf", "wb").write(requests.get("https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/raw/main/BarCvDescLJ11.pdf").content)
open("example_002.pdf", "wb").write(requests.get("https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/raw/main/Bill-Brown-Reprint.pdf").content)

# open PDF
l: SimpleParagraphExtraction = SimpleParagraphExtraction(maximum_multiplied_leading=1.6)
with open("example_002.pdf", "rb") as fh:
  doc = PDF.loads(fh, [l])

# build histogram (number of paragraphs per y-coordinate)
ps: typing.List[Paragraph] = l.get_paragraphs_for_page(0)
h: typing.Dict[int, int] = {}
for p in ps:
  y0: int = int(p.get_bounding_box().get_y())
  y1: int = int(y0 + p.get_bounding_box().get_height())
  for y in range(y0, y1):
    h[y] = h.get(y, 0) + 1

# display average
avg_paras_per_y: float = sum([x for x in h.values()]) / len(h)
print(avg_paras_per_y)
```

This outputs:

```
1.5903010033444815
```

On average, your two-column document has 1.6 paragraphs per y-coordinate. That would seem to indicate it's a two-column layout.

Comment: Could you try and do a mockup script with all the imports I don't know how to use your library I tried reading the GitHub, but that was different instruction than this one

Comment: If I don't bother you, can you further edit your answer to parse the PDF after the detection and save it as a string or to a txt file? If not, can you send me a link that shows how to use the text extraction tool. I'm new to python and kind of need help to work on it. Thank you

Comment: There is a very large examples repository, with a table of contents. You can easily search for keywords and check out the examples that match. Furthermore `borb` has over 300 tests, several of them work with the classes I've described here. You can ctrl+f for those classes inside the github repo and check out the matching files.